# *Compile-log* buffer warning

Tags: byte-compilation, install, warning

I am a newbie to Emacs Lisp. started Emacs and the `*Compile-log*` buffer shows the following logs which I don't have much clue of. I was trying to install `Magit` and `Helm`.

1. should anything in this log be concerning?
2. are the installations successful?
3. if possible, what does the log mean?

```
    Leaving directory ‘c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/with-editor-20200204.1828’

    Compiling file c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/with-editor-20200204.1828/with-editor.el at Fri Feb 14 09:11:47 2020
    Entering directory ‘c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/with-editor-20200204.1828/’

    In with-editor-finish:
    with-editor.el:347:51:Warning: assignment to free variable
        ‘git-commit-post-finish-hook’

    Compiling no file at Fri Feb 14 09:12:37 2020
    Leaving directory ‘c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/transient-20200125.1308’

    Compiling file c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/transient-20200125.1308/transient.el at Fri Feb 14 09:12:37 2020
    Entering directory ‘c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/transient-20200125.1308/’

    Compiling no file at Fri Feb 14 09:13:05 2020
    Leaving directory ‘c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/dash-20200119.2310’

    Compiling file c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/dash-20200119.2310/dash.el at Fri Feb 14 09:13:05 2020
    Entering directory ‘c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/dash-20200119.2310/’

    Compiling no file at Fri Feb 14 09:13:05 2020
    Leaving directory ‘c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/git-commit-20200207.1819’

    Compiling file c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/git-commit-20200207.1819/git-commit.el at Fri Feb 14 09:13:05 2020
    Entering directory ‘c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/elpa/git-commit-20200207.1819/’

    In helm-elisp--persistent-help:
    helm-lib.el:1054:40:Warning: reference to free variable
        `helm--buffer-in-new-frame-p'
    helm-lib.el:1056:38:Warning: reference to free variable
        `helm-persistent-action-window-buffer'

    In helm--prepare-completion-styles:
    helm-lib.el:1385:13:Warning: reference to free variable
        `helm-completion-style'
    helm-lib.el:1392:42:Warning: reference to free variable
        `helm-completion-styles-alist'
    helm-lib.el:1412:1:Warning: Unused lexical variable `helm-completion-style'

    In end of data:
    helm-lib.el:1581:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be
        defined: ffap-url-p, ffap-file-remote-p, helm-log-run-hook, helm-update,
        helm-get-selection, helm-set-case-fold-search

    In helm-resume:
    helm.el:2760:34:Warning: reference to free variable `helm-marked-buffer-name'
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you only see warnings and not errors, the installation is successful. Compilation warnings are relevant to the author of the package, but usually not to users.

Warnings may indicate that some functionality will not work. Often they don't: the compiler can only detect suspicious coding patterns, it can't tell whether the code actually works; and if there was a bug, there's a good chance that the package author would have fixed it.

“Reference to free variable” and “the following functions are not known to be defined” both indicate that the code is missing a compile-time declaration of the package that defines a symbol (variable or function). The package will still work as intended as long as the symbols are available at run time. The warnings about variables may be a concern eventually as more and more Emacs package declare variables lexically.